# Flutter: local_auth sometime do not present authentication dialog

Tags: flutter

I am using the flutter plugin local_auth 0.6.0+1. I am testing a basic implementation and I experience a strange behaviour in showing the auth dialog. I basically call the `checkIfCanAccessWithBiometric` method by pressing a button. Some time the dialog pops up immediately, some other time it takes a while, some other time does not pop up and it pops up only if I touch the screen. How can I resolve this issue?? thanks

```
  void checkIfCanAccessWithBiometric() async {
    bool didAuthenticate = await _localAuth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
        localizedReason: 'Please authenticate to login', 
        stickyAuth: true);
    print(didAuthenticate);
  }
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Nope. Let me start a bounty